# How to sensibly set bar width in matplotlib.axes.bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

When adding a bar plot, eg

```
an_axis.bar(xvalues, yvalues)
```

The default bar width [is 0.8](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/axes_api.html), but my plots have a variable number of bars & risk getting messed up with the width set manually.

Is there a good way to set the bar width programmatically?

Comment: width of what? could you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the utter vagueness of the question! I've clarified. (I planned to link direct to the axis.bar() API, but forgot to update what I'd written after realising a direct link was impossible. Doh!)

Answer (score 0):

OK - this seems to work:

```
minx, maxx = plt.getp(ax2, 'xbound')
ax2.bar(xvalues, yvalues,
        width=(maxx-minx)/len(xvalues))
```

Which I was able to figure out after discovering:

```
plt.getp(object) # In this case ax2
```

Without additional parameters this gives a list of properties & their values; very useful for exploring matplotlib objects.